# How to create a discrete distribution in OpenTURNS?

Tags: openturns

I have a sample of real values which contains independent realizations of a discrete random variable and I want to create the distribution which fits this data.

```
sample = [2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

The `UserDefined` distribution seems to be designed for this purpose, but requires to compute the weights of each point, depending on its frequency in the sample:

```
import openturns as ot
distribution = ot.UserDefined(points, weights)
```

But we have to compute the `points` and `weights` first. To do this, I computed the points and weights using the Numpy `unique` function. However, this sounds like a limitation of the `UserDefined` class. How may I do this more simply?

Answer (score 0):

The `UserDefinedFactory` class creates a `UserDefined` distribution by estimating the `points` and `weights` from the sample. The `build` method takes the sample as input and returns the `ot.UserDefined` object that fits the data.

```
import openturns as ot
sample = ot.Sample([[2.0], [2.0], [1.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [1.0], [2.0], [2.0], [1.0]])
factory = ot.UserDefinedFactory()
distribution = factory.build(sample)
```